# How do I prompt user to save text (xml) to a file?

Tags: javascript, xml, save-as

I've have some javascript code that transforms XML with XSLT.  I now want the user to be able to save that new XML (either by prompting them or throwing the new XML up as a file or something so that the user can then save it.  Anybody know how to do that?

```
var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmldoc.async = false;
xmldoc.loadXML(responseText); // responseText is xml returned from ajax call
//apply the xslt
var xsldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xsldoc.async = false;
xsldoc.load("../xslt/ExtraWorkRequest.xslt");
var content = xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
```

How do I get the user to save the XML (content) as a file?

Comment: Do you want this to work for any browser other than IE?

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can't. Browser isn't supposed to access your local disks for security reasons.

But, *if you can ask your user to change it's security settings* (and you should not to ask), you can to use `FileSystemObject` or even your `Microsoft.XMLDOM.Save` method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with 100% client-side JavaScript with the default security settings. You'll need to implement some server-side logic. In your case, you'll be able to do the XML transformation server-side, as well.

http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-javascripts-ijfTJlI9/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q260519/

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a data: URI with a media type of `application/octet-stream`.

```
function download (data, charset) {
  if (!charset) {
    charset = document.characterSet;
  }
  location.href = ["data:application/octet-stream;charset=",
                   charset, ",", encodeURIComponent(data)
                  ].join("");
}
```

All browsers except IE support data: URIs. I think IE8 may support them, but only for images. For IE, a workaround could be to send the data to a server (including `document.characterSet`) and then load a page that has something like the following header:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset={document.characterSet}
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

If you want to give the file a name too, use `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`.

Also, for any of this to work, you have to convert your XML to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with code snippets on [my blog](http://blog.josh420.com) (user can click on the save button, and the snippet will come up in their default text editor, where they can tweak it and/or copy it into their app).

It works by putting all the textual data inside of a hidden field, and then submits it to a very simple server-side HTTP handler.  The handler just grabs the hidden field value and spits it right back out in the response with the right content-disposition header, giving the user the open/save download prompt.

This is the only way I could get it to work.