# "Save as"-button in IE, save file on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, internet-explorer

Is there any way to make a button that generates a text/xml file, sets the content-type to application-download, adds an attachment etc on the client side? What i want is a "download"-button on my page that saves an xml-file. This is how i do the same thing on serverside:

```
response.StatusCode = 200;
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF32;
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", response.ContentEncoding.GetByteCount(xmlString).ToString());
        response.ContentType = "application-download";
        response.Write(xmlString);
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is ASP.NET with C#?

Comment: @JanHančič Yes, javascript/jquery

Comment: @Carlito Yes, my example is in c#, but i want to do the same thing on the clientside

Comment: Are you willing to use Flash?

Comment: @Pekka as long as it doesnt require any external files, yes. I suppose it requires a separate .swf though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate some xml in javascript, prompt user to save it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226192/generate-some-xml-in-javascript-prompt-user-to-save-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to create the file in jQuery/Javascript and be able to save it to disk from the browser, the answer is plain NO. Javascript is not allowed (for security reasons) to save to disk, neither to make the browser throw a "Save as..." popup for something locally created.
You have an easier solution to your question. In your example you are creating the xml file and sending it as an attachment from the server, why dont you just make a button to download the file created by the server?
You can't do it by plain ajax, cause it can't trigger downloads in the browser, but you can use the old "iframe download trick" to launch the download in the same page.

```
function download(url_to_your_creating_file_servlet){
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = url_to_your_creating_file_servlet;
}
```

Or if you don't mind to open another window/tab (a bit uglier) this also works:

```
<a href="url_to_your_creating_file_servlet" target="blank"> Download </a>
```